# Whats the name for a javascript pattern with a variable that is assigned the return value of a function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

What the proper name of this Javascript pattern where a variable is assigned to value of a return function?

```
// array with a ton of random values. 
var once = (function(){

        var i = 10000, arr = [];

        while(i){
            arr.push( Math.random() * i );
            i--;
        }
        arr = arr.toString(); 

        return (function(){
            return arr;
        }());

}());
```

Edit - a better example:

```
 var once = (function(){

    // Only run a really expensive operation once...
    var i = 10000, arr = [], x;

    while(i){
        arr.push( Math.random() * i );
        i--;
    }
    arr = arr.toString(); 
    x = parseFloat(arr.toString());

    // then return the result of another function
    return function(){
        return x * (Math.random() * 10);
    };

}());

$(window).resize(function(){
    console.info(once());
});
```

Comment: Just "assignment"?

Comment: The return value of an _anonymous_ function, that is. Otherwise, it's just a plain old function call return.

Comment: maybe "self executing function" is what you're looking for? Also in this example there doesn't seem to be any reason to return arr in a new function scope, but it may just be a contrived example.

Comment: I don't think it has a name.  It's a fairly standard idiom in any language with first class functions.  Are you wanting the name to know what to call it in conversation, or to learn more about it?

Comment: After your edit, I think you might mean mean memoization?

Comment: Ah. I actually should have realized that off of the original question, especially with the method called 'once'.  Questions about closures or anonymous functions crop up a lot though :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

> In computing, memoization is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by having function calls avoid repeating the calculation of results for previously processed inputs.
>
> ...
>
> A memoized function "remembers" the results corresponding to some set of specific inputs. Subsequent calls with remembered inputs return the remembered result rather than recalculating it, thus eliminating the primary cost of a call with given parameters from all but the first call made to the function with those parameters.

Comment: Ahh.. I couldn't see the forest for the trees.  +1

Comment: @gilly3 If it makes you feel any better, I thought that's what he was asking too.  I think we're all used to the "why does jQuery do this?" or "What does this mean?" closure questions lol.

Answer (score 2):

That is a self-invoking anonymous function.

It is useful when you want to do some work, but keep the variables out of scope.  This can be particularly important if you are worried about memory leaks - the variables used in the anonymous function go immediately out of scope, and can be cleaned up by the garbage collector.  Of course, if you return a closure, the opposite happens - those variables remain for the life of the closure.

**Edit:**  Your second example is a closure. Your closure looks a lot like your self invoking anonymous function, but, as I mentioned above, it behaves quite differently.

I'd go on a bit more about closures, but I'm answering from my phone, and that kind of an answer requires all ten fingers...   maybe I'll come back to this later.

Comment: well not quite "self" invoking, but that's what people call it.

Comment: Some people prefer the term "Immediately invoked function expression" (IIFE) to avoid the self thing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it "currying"?

A function of N arguments that is considered as a function of one argument which returns another function of N-1 arguments.

Comment: "Currying" refers to the practice of creating a function that captures an argument. It is not really possible to do real currying in JavaScript because JavaScript is not a lazy evaluation language.

Comment: @Pointy so to formally count as currying, the original function must be able to take an expression and then the curried function must be able to evaluate that expression internally at call time?  Never knew that.  I always assumed that just being able to bind on a primitive constituted currying.  Looks like I have some Wikipedia to  read :).

Comment: The thing is that lazy evaluation languages like Haskell are where you can really see the process in action. In "eager" languages, it's sort-of a fake.